# Update query stuck forever

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, rdbms

I am executing following UPDATE sql query against oracle database server -

```
UPDATE TEST.SS_USER_CREDENTIALS SET CREDENTIAL = 'UUHs4w4Nk45gHrSIHA==';
```

After executing this query in Oracle SQL developer, I can see spinner of execution status of query keeps spinning forever and hence no output is returned. However following SELECT query on same table returns result immediately -

```
 SELECT  * FROM TEST.SS_USER_CREDENTIALS;
```

Could you please help to understand why UPDATE query is not executed?

Comment: how many rows are in your table? It may take a while to update if there are millions of rows. Also, are there any triggers on that field? That could also take time.

Comment: THere are on 49 rows in the table.

Comment: Any triggers? or ON UPDATE clauses?

Answer (score 0):

try with where clause

```
UPDATE TEST.SS_USER_CREDENTIALS SET CREDENTIAL = 'UUHs4w4Nk45gHrSIHA==' where id='someid';
```

as I see your command if the table has trillion of rows it will take time (as I guess this should not be foreign key)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

If you are looking for a temp solution you can also change the ON UPDATE action to CASCADE and modify your ids if you got a foreign key problem

Comment: Even for single row as you mentioned, it stuck forever.

Comment: it can be you have another open uncommitted transaction for the same set of records, so they are locked for that transaction.if you locked them, running the same UPDATE in another transaction.

Just Commit/rollback your transactions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have autocommit enabled, you may need to run 
COMMIT;

Otherwise oracle updates aren't actually applied to your data set

Comment: I have COMMIT after query mentioned in question but it never reaches COMMIT as it stuck for that query.

Comment: There could be an existing transaction occuring on that table. Are you rurnning this from a local environment, or is it on a database server that someone else could have also have an open transaction on that table? Oracle has a way of checking tables for open transactions 

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-can-i-check-open-transactions-oracle-database

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the link which helps to identify open transactions! But before reading your comment, unfortunately out of frustration, I restated the database server and executed those commands manually to proceed which is wrong practise.

Answer (score 0):

it can be you have another open uncommitted transaction for the same set of records, so they are locked for that transaction.

if you locked them, running the same UPDATE in another transaction.

Just Commit/rollback your transactions

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But these queries are running through Jenkins pipeline and in pipeline, I don't have multiple transactions on same table. Unfortunately out of frustration, I restated the database server and executed those commands manually to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Close the database connection and refresh it
2. Refresh the table
3. Restart the SQL Server in services

I know this is not a complete answer to this, hope it helped!